# Assembly 8086 : Strange behavior of the system time

Tags: assembly, time, delay, sleep, x86-16

I'm writing a delay function in Assembly 8086. To do so, I'm using the system time. First I reset the time and then I loop until the system time is equal or larger to the time I wanted to wait.

This shouldn't be very difficult. 
So this is my delay procedure :

```
delay_using_time PROC NEAR
push bp    
mov bp, sp

push ax
push bx
push cx
push dx

; Set system time (CH = Hour, CL = minute, DH = second, DL = 1/100 sec)
mov ah, 2Dh
xor cx, cx  ; Now CH = 0 = CL
xor dx, dx  ; DX = 0 = DH = DL 
int 21h

; We check that the reset did not failed
CMP al, 0  ; Als al = 255 dan is het setten van de system time mislukt
JNE exit_delay

mov bl, [bp+4][0] ; We put the argument in BL --> wait time

; Debug --> Prints always 0 (so reset was succesfull)
mov dl, dh 
xor dh, dh
push dx
call tprint

; Loop untill DL = wait time, but the problem is DL is immediately bigger
compareTime:
mov ah, 2Ch
int 21h      ; #sec in DH, #1/100 sec in DL

; For debug --> I print the number of seconds passed since we reset the time
mov dl, dh 
xor dh, dh
push dx
call tprint

; If #seconds < wait time (argument) --> loop again until #seconds >= wait time 
CMP dl, bl    

JL compareTime 
JMP exit_delay

exit_delay:
pop dx
pop cx
pop bx
pop ax

mov sp, bp
pop bp 
ret 2
delay_using_time ENDP
```

But my delay procedure doesn't work. So I put displays into it to see where the problem comes from.

First i display the seconds after I reset the system time. It displays 0, so the system time was reset correctly. After that in the loop I display the number of seconds passed since I reset the system time. I would expect something like this 1,1, ..., 1, 2, 2, ..., 2, 3 to be displayed when I pass as argument 3 (so I want to delay for 3 seconds).
(each number is displayed many times because it is looping and it loops many times per second).

**But** when I test my procedure, I see **the loop is only executed once each time I call delay!**
So it displays directly for example "54" instead of 1, 2, 3, ..., 54 (what we would expect).

Can someone tell me why it is behaving like that? I really don't understand, I first reset the system time and displayed it to be sure it was reset and then in the loop I display the number of seconds. So **the number of seconds jump immediately from 0 (when I reset it) to for example 54.**

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why do you set time with ah=2d, first? Also I am not sure if any gettime call destroys any registers. Morealso you destroy dl with mov dl, dh.

Comment: @bestsss I first set the time to midnight (hour, minutes, seconds and hundreds to zero) because I pass as an argument to my function the time it has to delay/sleep. So once I reset the time to midnight after that all i have to do is check the time and compare the seconds (time passed since I reset it) with the argument passed to the procedure. If the time passed < the argument I loop again. So that I'm looping until the time passed >= argument. And yes get time  put his result in CX and DX registers : CH = hour CL = minute DH = second DL = 1/100 seconds. Set time info : http://bit.ly/1Bp9gTu

Comment: @bestsss I destroy dl with mov dl, dh because I want to pass the number of seconds (dh) to a procedure that will display the argument (is a number passed via the stack). So if I would push DX on the stack the displayed number would be wrong because DX = (DH DL). So to display the number of seconds correctly (dh) I copy DH into DL. And then clear DH (xor dh, dh) so that when it will display the content of DX it will actually display DL (because DH is zero and thus won't change the value of DL). Sorry for the double comment but it was to long to fit in one comment.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code last night and it performed correctly. I got thousands of zeroes, ones and twoes and a single three.
Your program has an obvious way to run just 1 time if the exit value of function 2Dh were anything else than 0. Under a real DOS exit values should only be 0 or 255. Did you try comparing with 255 and jumping if equal? Furthermore you could differentiate between a normal exit and an exit due to not resetting the time correctly as a debugging aid. A beep perhaps?

This comment is not entirely right

```
; Debug --> Prints always 0 (so reset was succesfull)
```

You print the original 0 that you've put in the DH register!
Also

```
JMP exit_delay
```

and

```
mov sp, bp
```

are rather superfluous.

Comment: Indeed, when I'm using seconds it works fine. But when I try to delay an amount of 1/100 seconds, like 5 hundreds of a second, it behaves strange. So all i changed is i printed the value of dl instead of dh (so the 1/100 seconds are displayed). And I also compare dl with bl, instead of dh with bl (compare seconds). So we would expect it to just like with seconds display something like "000..0111..122..233..344..455..5" if we pass as argument 5 (so to wait 5 hundreds of a second). But the number displayed is immediately like 56. Is 5/100 sec below the precision limits of the timer?

Comment: The value that MS-DOS returns for the hundredths of seconds is based on the BIOS timer tick which operates at 18.2 ticks per second. So the resolution is about 55 msec. I ran a modified version of your code and got these values in DL during 1 second (each number appeared many times in a row). **0,5,10,16,21,27,32,38,43,49,54,60,65,71,76,82,87,93,98,4** The increase of 5 or 6 corresponds to 100/18.2  In short MS-DOS tries hard to give the illusion of a very accurate time but the hardware doesn't allow it.